# Sub/center shifted on 5.1 sound

Tags: sound, usb, multimedia

Hi I bought "Device 002: ID 0d8c:0102 C-Media Electronics, Inc. CM106 Like Sound Device" and it works, except that center go to sub and wise versa. I have Logitech z906 as speakersystem. I know that C-media pci-soundcard for 20 years ago have a jumpers that change sub/center, but this is a usb-device.What can I do, except revirering the phone-plug? I have Ubunbtu 22:04